# Entity Framework (code first) creates unecessary duplicated foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have something like the following typical code:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And Entity Framework creates something like:

```
create table Children
(
    Id int identity constraint [PK_dbo.Children] primary key,
    Parent_Id int
        constraint FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parent_Parent_Id
            references Parents,
}
```

Then I add cascade delete by:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasMany(x => x.Children)
    .WithRequired()
    //.HasForeignKey(x => x.Parent) // my wrong try 
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

And EF creates something like:

```
create table Children
(
    Id int identity constraint [PK_dbo.Children] primary key,
    Parent_Id int
        constraint FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parent_Parent_Id
            references Parents,
    Parent_Id1 int
        constraint FK_dbo.Children_dbo.Parent_Parent_Id1
            references Parents,
    ...
}
```

i.e. EF create duplicated FK: `Parent_Id` and `Parent_Id1`. Why?

I tried different variants but i couldn't get rid of the unnecessary duplicates.

Please, can anyone help to solve this issue?

**Update:**

Michael, thank you much for your response. I read this article and tried different variants, but unfortunately without success. The `[InverseProperty("Parent")]` attribute also did not help.

In my case `Parent.Children` is `ApplicationUser.YmSites`. And `Child.Parent` is `YmSite.User`.

Just now, I even try the following direct T-SQL script:

```
ALTER TABLE DB_9B2F.dbo.YmSites DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.YmSites_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id]
ALTER TABLE DB_9B2F.dbo.YmSites
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.YmSites_dbo.AspNetUsers_User_Id]
FOREIGN KEY (User_Id) REFERENCES AspNetUsers (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But I get the error:

> This property is not supported: ApplicationName.

Very strange.

Comment: The problem is `.WithRequired()`. It has to be `.WithRequired(x => x.Parent)`. Always use the correct overload, otherwise you'll end up with a second relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The problem

1. EF already created the relationship, and it was cascade delete enabled
2. Then you have defined it again with the `DbModelBuilder`

In short i thought you had 2 relationships. so, you don't need to do anything, just delete the `DbModelBuilder` code

However, if you needed to do something with the model builder like turning cascade delete off, or you just want it there for redundancy (who knows why). One way you can achieve this is by explicitly telling *EF* that you have a relationship (one) between `Parent` and `Child` using the *InverseProperty* data annotation

```
public class Parent 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [InverseProperty("Parent")]
  public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

***Note*** : usually inverse property is to declare multiple relationships, however in this case it works because you are making it known you just want that relationship

---

For a complete answer, i tried to find someone else's word for it below.

[Cascade Delete in One-to-Many Relationships](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx)

> **Note**: EF automatically deletes related records in the middle table for
>   many-to-many relationship entities if one or the other entity is
>   deleted.
>
> **Thus, EF enables the cascading delete effect by default for all the
>   entities.**